# output content of a table as one line in mysql sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to output a purchase order into one line that has product and quantity of each product.

say

> select product, quantity from order;

outputs

```
product A , 2
product B , 3
product C , 7
```

I need the output to be in one line:

```
product A,2,product B,3,product C, 7
```

Can this be achieved using mysql sql ?

Comment: you should use the `group_concat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*try this:*

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product,',' ,quantity) FROM ORDERS;
```

*see the sqlfiddle:*

***http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d18e6/7***

Answer (score 0):

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1826c/12/0)**</kbd>

#### Query

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product, ',' ,quantity,'') FROM order1;
```

#### Result

```
|------------------------------------------------|
|GROUP_CONCAT(PRODUCT, ',' ,QUANTITY,'')         |
|------------------------------------------------|
|product A,2,product B,3,product C,7             |
|------------------------------------------------|
```